# ios keyboards are different height

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, uitextfield, custom-keyboard

i have a really weird situation with my app.

I am showing a default keyboard in my app but it looks stretched (see screenshot 1)
[image: not the same height of the keyboard]

this does not happen in other apps like twitter (see screenshot 2)
[image: same height when comparing twitter and imessage]

anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well. If you are running your app on an iPhone 6 or 6 Plus and have not yet provided app launch images for those particular devices then the iOS will scale the screen size up instead of calculating UI elements based on the actual size of the device.

Solution: Provide launch images for all device sizes.